# Автоматические уведомления о новых вопросах и ответах, требующих проверки

Tags: поддержка, очередь-проверок

Имеется ли функционал, уведомляющий модератора (в значении «пользователь с репутацией ≥ 500» ) о новых вопросах и ответах или запоздалых ответах? Каким образом опытные модераторы Stack Overflow узнают о появлении новых изменений, требующих проверки? Спасибо.

Comment: Судя по всему, жмут F5 на странице очередей проверок :)

Answer (score 3):

Встроенных оповещений такого рода нет. Некоторые фанаты проверок используют скрипты:

- [Review Stalker user script](https://stackapps.com/q/4086)
- [Review Stalker Reloaded: A cross-site dashboard for reviews](https://stackapps.com/q/6869)

Есть ещё расширение для Chrome: [Review+ Page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/review%20-page/nfaaglhemabjbpddkbahiogfclhkablj), которое я написал пару лет назад. Одна из его функций добавляет индикаторы очередей проверки в верхнюю часть страницы (на всех страницах сайта). Пример взят с английского сайта, где очередей больше:

[image: topbar]

Если индикатор загорелся, значит что-то есть; и клик по индикатору ведёт напрямую в эту очередь.

Но в большинстве своём, проверяющие открывают страницу проверок по своему собственному усмотрению: тогда, когда у них есть на это время и желание.  В частности, я давно перестал использовать своё расширение.

Comment: Установил. Судя по всему суть скриптов заключается в автоматическом обновлении страницы http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review , которая должна быть всегда открыта. Лучше, на мой взгляд, реализовать уведомления о проверке также, как здесь выполнены уведомления об изменении репутации или ответах или комментариях в твой адрес. К примеру, находясь на любой странице http://ru.stackoverflow.com , модератору бы сверху показывалось количество сообщений, ожидающих проверки. Есть время и желание — проверил, и не нужно держать открытой страницу проверок. Спасибо.

Comment: Добавил ссылку на расширение такого рода.

Comment: Жаль, для Chrome, не Firefox( . А расширение полезно. Проверять ведь никто не обязывает, а когда есть желание/время, в очереди проверок часто оказываются нули. Спасибо!