# Кнопка «Комментировать»

Tags: дефект, дизайн

Оставил сейчас [комментарий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2881/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8#comment9008_2881) к одному вопросу здесь, на Мете.

[Кнопка «Комментировать» http://pokit.org/get/img/952c53cae8cee2ab742d6acebf70fedc.jpg](http://pokit.org/get/img/952c53cae8cee2ab742d6acebf70fedc.jpg)

Как видно на скрине, кнопка проходит под цифрой, но закрывает первую букву похожего вопроса.

---

**UPD**: дефект проявляется, когда на открытой странице появляются комментарии, внесённые после того момента, как ты зашёл на эту страницу, и нажатия <kbd>показать ещё 1 комментарий</kbd> → <kbd>добавить комментарий</kbd>. На 2-м скриншоте видно, что кнопка уходит вправо, а также уменьшается ширина предшествующих комментариев, из-за чего они становятся вертикальными.

[Снова она http://pokit.org/get/img/2a47bea43e9f85eed288d53445811a81.jpg](http://pokit.org/get/img/2a47bea43e9f85eed288d53445811a81.jpg)

Windows, браузер Pale Moon, тема sky palace, окрашивающая панели браузера оттенками зелёного. Через Gracemonkey установлено оформление для ВКонтакте, Фэйсбука, YouTube и некоторых других сайтов, но не Stack Overflow. Для проектов Stack Exchange установлены расширения [Review Stalker и Review Stalker Reloaded](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2846/199934). Спасибо.

Comment: Что за браузер и почему ширина скриншота меньше минимальной ширины страницы?

Comment: Вероятно, у вас есть какие-то пользовательские стили, потому что сайт имеет жёсткую ширину в 1060px, равно как и поле для ввода комментария.

Comment: У вас не только кнопка поехала, но и текст комментариев, и поле ввода нового комментария. Попробуйте использовать более популярный браузер. 

Думаю, пользователи Pale Moon составляют несущественную долю пользователей Stack Exchange. Соответственно, поддержка совместимости с Pale Moon скорее всего невыгодна и рассчитывать на починку не стоит.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ни у кого больше [так](http://pokit.org/get/img/4c9ce3e1be094166d18b70317dc8d9ba.jpg) комментарии не сужались? А если только в моём браузере — что ж, перетерпим эту мелочь.

Comment: @СашаЧерных проверил на FF и Chromium - в норме вёрстка.